# How to update the State on a DnD Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

I'm currently trying to use a Drag & Drop Library called **[dnd-kit](http://docs.dndkit.com/presets/sortable)** and its hook called useSortable.

So far I did achieved to make everything draggable the way I like, unfortunately somehow its not possible for me to update the state accordingly to the dragging.

**Attached you can find also an example of my code.**

I'm glad for every suggestion to solve my problem :)

```
 
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { DndContext } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import { arrayMove, SortableContext, useSortable } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import { CSS } from "@dnd-kit/utilities";

function SortableItem({ item }) {
  const { id, name } = item;
  const {
    attributes,
    listeners,
    setNodeRef,
    transform,
    transition
  } = useSortable({ id: id });

  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
    transition
  };

  return (
    <li ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes} {...listeners} draggable>
      Movement for {name}
    </li>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Items One" },
    { id: 2, name: "Item 2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Items 3" }
  ]);

  const handleDragEnd = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (active.id !== over.id) {
        setItems((items) => {
            console.log(items);
            const oldIndex = items.indexOf(active.id);
            const newIndex = items.indexOf(over.id);
            const newItemsArray = arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
            return newItemsArray;
        });
    }
};

  console.log(items);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Sorting Example</h1>

      <DndContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
        <SortableContext items={items}>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <SortableItem key={item.id} item={item} />
          ))}
        </SortableContext>
      </DndContext>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit sharp-paper-qbrrh]

Comment: Have a look at: https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-kit-sortable-example-c1gtn?file=/src/App.jsx it has helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You're main issue is in these lines:

```js
const oldIndex = items.indexOf(active.id);
const newIndex = items.indexOf(over.id);
```

Since you're using an array of objects and not just an array, you'll need to find the index through `find` as well and not just `indexOf` to get its index. Like so:

```js
const oldItem = items.find({ id }) => id === active.id)
const newItem = items.find({ id }) => id === over.id)
const oldIndex = items.indexOf(oldItem);
const newIndex = items.indexOf(newItem);
const newItemsArray = arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
```

If you're using typescript, any linting can complain that `oldItem` or `newItem` can be `undefined` and `indexOf` doesn't accept `undefined`s, so you can just use `!` to force it because you know that the item will exist (usually), e.g.: `const oldIndex = items.indexOf(oldItem!);`

**Update:** or even better/cleaner using `findIndex` as suggested by [@Ashiq Dey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71707036/842768):

```js
const oldIndex = items.findIndex({ id }) => id === active.id)
const newIndex = items.findIndex({ id }) => id === over.id)
const newItemsArray = arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with how you are trying to match id in indexOf method. if your items array looks like this

```
[
  {id:1,name:"Item 1"},
  {id:3,name:"Item 2"},
  {id:4,name:"Item 3"}
]
```

then you should use the below code to make the match for respective id `f.id === active.id` but you were just passing the value of id and  not making a conditional match.

```
function handleDragEnd(event) {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (active.id !== over.id) {
        setItems((items) => {
            const oldIndex = items.findIndex(f => f.id === active.id);
            const newIndex = items.findIndex(f => f.id === over.id);
            return arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @giovannipds provides a helpful explanation why this answer is correct, though I find this code a little cleaner.